# What is Time of Validity in a GPS System?

Tags: gps, time, terminology

What is time of validity in a GPS system?  For defining time of validity, there are only a limited definitions available.  My interpretation for time of validity is the built-in system time (like on your computer) while GPS time is time from the GPS receiver.

Comment: This might help https://support.spirent.com/SC_KnowledgeView?Id=SOL10184 note: almanac time is the same for all satellites whereas the ephemeris time is unique to each satellite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just the time for which your GPS data is valid. Between these times the data is good to use. It is only used by certain vendors and not all. Here you go. https://portal.u-blox.com/s/question/0D52p00008HKCvtCAH/time-accuracy-estimate-and-time-validity. Here is some more https://www.novatel.com/support/known-solutions/gnss-ephemerides-and-almanacs/